# What is the meaning of the "will already have...." structure?

Tags: grammar, future, future-perfect

I am wondering about the meaning of a sentence which includes the "will already have...." structure?
The exact sentence is a part of IELTS practice test which says:

" ....in today’s tutorial we’re going to discuss the essays that you have to submit by the end of next week. Some of you will have already started them,... ".

Tnx

Comment: *Will* is used because the statement is a conjecture - the tutor doesn't actually know that some of the students have started but can make an educated guess. This is like *they left an hour ago so they'll be there by now*.  *... have started* is used because the starting is an event in the past with current relevance, and because the past simple cannot be used with *will*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply a declarative clause in the **Future Perfect** tense.

The formula is : Subject will have Perfect Participle (Complement).

*Some of **you** **will** **have** already **started** **them**,*

**you**==subject

**will + have** = future perfect auxiliary verbs

**started**== principle verb(in its past participle form).

**them**== Complement-> Direct Object.

**already**= just an adverb->Adjunct .

And as exactly stated in your sentence *by the end of next week*.
Future Perfect is usually used when an action takes place before another in the future.

This website is quite comprehensive when it comes to tense.
https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureperfect.html